Find a measurable function $g(x)$ that minimizes the mathematical expectation $E(-24Y^4+(g(X))^2+2g(X)Y^2+4)$
I have a random vector that is normally distributed
$$
X, Y=N\left(\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
2\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1\\
1&2\\
\end{pmatrix}\right).
$$
Find a measurable function $g(x)$ that minimizes the mathematical expectation
$$E(-24Y^4+(g(X))^2+2g(X)Y^2+4).$$
Inside $E(-24Y^4+(g(X))^2+2g(X)Y^2+4)$ can select a complete square. Then we get
$E(-24Y^4+(g(X))^2+2g(X)Y^2+4)=E((Y^2+g(X))^2-25Y^2+4)$.
The search for the optimal $f(x)$ is equivalent to the search for the optimal value $E((Y^2+g(X))^2)$.
I've reached this point, but I don't know what to do next. Please help me figure out the problem.

Are you sure that the 3rd term is $2g(X)Y^2$ instead of $2g(X)Y$? The problem is much nicer in the second case, and it seems you may have made a mistake while completing the square that hints at a typo.

@Jan Yes, thank you very much, I have a typo, but not in the third multiplier, but in the first one, it should be there -24Y^4

What is the source of this problem?
